# PLSQL APPLE push notifiactions

Tags: oracle, plsql, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem with notifications. 
I'm using Oracle apex with rest services.

How to send push notifications to APN iphone from pl/sql?
Are you using Java in database?

Answer (score 1):

We successfully implemented the solution in our java code with [java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns)

You create a service:

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = Thread
    .currentThread()
    .getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("Certificate.p12");

ApnsService service = APNS.newService()
    .withCert(resourceAsStream, "CERTNAME")
    .withProductionDestination()
    .build();
```

Then you create a payload:

```
String payload = APNS.newPayload()
    .sound("default")
    .alertBody(generatePushMessageBody(...))
    .customField("title", generateTitleForPushMessage(user))
    .customField("startDate", formatDateForPushMessage(...)
    .customField("username", user.getUserName())
    .build();
```

And then send the push notification:

```
service.push(registrationId, payload);
```

You need to put this code to a PL/SQL stored procedure and it will work.

Comment: Can you send me example. How you put java-apns in database? Do you have example package?
Thanks