# Apple Push Notifications from PL SQL

Tags: ios, ssl, plsql, oracle11g, apple-push-notifications

I have read this answer:
[PLSQL APPLE push notifiactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041089/plsql-apple-push-notifiactions/26041223#26041223)

but I cannot use Java.
I believe there should be a way to contact APNS from PL/SQL, because I have already implemented GCM(Android notifications) using PL/SQL.

How certificates are set up:
I have one pem file which contains Apple Push Certificate and Private key.
I also have entrust's root certificate. I added them to the wallet using orapki.

I am not good at PL/SQL, so there might be some problem in my code:

```html
v_url VARCHAR2(200) := 'https://gateway.push.apple.com:2195'; -- APNS url
v_request_body        RAW(32767);

  -- payload prep
  v_token := '01234567890123456789012345678922';
  v_data := '{ "aps" : { "alert" : "This is the alert text", "badge" : 1, "sound" : "default" }';
  v_data_length := length(v_data);
  
  v_request_body := UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(0)||
                    UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(0)||
                    UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(32)||
                    UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(v_token)||
                    UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(0)||
                    UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(v_data_length)||
                    UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(v_data);
                    
  v_request_length := UTL_RAW.length(r => v_request_body);
  
  -- request starts here
  UTL_HTTP.set_wallet(path => 'file:/path/wallet', password => 'walletPass');  
  req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url => v_url, method => 'POST');
  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(r     => req,
                      name  => 'Content-Type',
                      value => 'application/octet-stream');
  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(r     => req,
                      name  => 'Content-Length',
                      value => v_request_length);

--  UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT(r => req, data => v_request_body);
  utl_http.write_raw(r => req, data => v_request_body);

  resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

The code above after run returns this Error: Fatal SSL Error

Similar as in this post: [ORA-28860: Fatal SSL error when using UTL_HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932660/ora-28860-fatal-ssl-error-when-using-utl-http)

The author of the answer to that post says:

> There is also a bug 20323753 registered for 11.2.0.4 recently, still not fixed.

Thats the version I have, but I still think thats not the problem.
I might be missing something important about APNS or PL/SQL

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Zhandos, did you ever get this to work?
Have you tried pushing messages through the sandbox?
gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com

Further, I'm not sure whether using UTL_HTTP is the correct approach here, as this is not a HTTP service?
I'm trying to achieve the same using UTL_TCP, although I'm having other issues to get set the certificate correct:

```html
declare
  l_tcp_conn utl_tcp.connection;
  l_returnvalue     number;
begin

  -- open connection
  l_tcp_conn  := utl_tcp.open_connection('gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', 2195, charset     => 'US7ASCII');

  -- secure the connection
  UTL_TCP.SECURE_CONNECTION(l_tcp_conn);

  -- write to TCP stream
  l_returnvalue := utl_tcp.write_line(l_tcp_conn, 'payload goes here');
  

end;
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks.